# How can I set the control's tab index?

Tags: winapi, tabs, windows-10, tabindex

Does winapi supports something like [`Control.TabIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex)? if not, how is this usually implemented? Do I have to process the key tab press from a `WM_KEYDOWN` message and set focus on the control accordingly or is there something native to do that? I have no code to show yet because I'm trying to figure out how begun to do that.

Comment: I believe that tab order is implied by the order in which controls are created. [How can I create a non-circular tab order, or some other type of custom ordering in my Win32 dialog?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201231-00/?p=104627) explains how to manually adjust the tab order at runtime.

Comment: Tab order is based on z-order. Z-order is based on creation order, but could be modified with `SetWindowPos( hwnd, other_hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );`

Comment: When you have a dialogbox created from resources, you can change control declaration order in it's resource template to change their z-order.

Comment: In the Visual Studio dialog editor, press Ctrl-D to change control order.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, this also works but in my case `SetWindowPos()` fits well, that I ended up using.

Comment: @DanielSęk Post this answer answer so I can accept

Comment: @nevilad I don't have a dialog box created from resources and I needed to change it at runtime

Comment: @JonathanPotter it isn't a dialog nor I'm using VS dialog editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab order is based o z-order (order in which children are painted). Initially z-order is based on creation order, so controls are painted and tabbed in same order as creation order.

When creating controls this could be changed by reordering creation sequence (in code or *.rc file).

After creation use `SetWindowPos( hwnd, other_hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );` to rearrange controls in z-order.